# Unresolved reference: Typeface findFromCache

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

`Typeface` class contains a static `findFromCache` method:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java

I also see the method in IntelliJ in `Typeface` source code.

However, when I try to use it I get `Unresolved reference: findFromCache` error. My current API version is 28. Target API 26.

Why does it show an error when the method is present in the SDK?

Comment: I checked the documentation from developer website and there is no method present that you have named. check here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface

Comment: @KaranMer I know. However, it's there in the sources and IntelliJ shows the method in SDK as well. It's public.

Comment: I checked in android studio for api 28 and its not here as well.

Comment: however it is there in api 27 sources.

Comment: This is bug in android studio. i submitted bug on this and google team mention that they will fix this bug in next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API has an "annotation" [`@hide`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java#291), this means it is an undocumented / hidden API, which are prohibited to use [since Android API 28](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

Comment: Some related news, discussions can be searched with keyword "android api 28 hide", for example [in XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-undocumented-hidden-apis-android-p/), or [in CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/18/think-hard-about-hide.html).